# Wp-Insert in not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a form submission code in wordpress. I have created a sign up form. I have added a table named 'users' and used wp-insert query for insertion. 
Here is my code

```
$wpdb->insert( 'users', array( 'name' => 'abc', 'email'=>'abc@xyz.com', 'phone'=>546546545, 'cell'=>21432132, 'user_name'=>'abc', 'user_password'=>'987sdf554'), array('%s','%s','%d','%d','%s','%s'));
```

And my table fields are:
1) user_id /*It is auto increment*/
2) name
3) email
4) phone
5) cell
6) user_name
7) user_password

Can any one guide me what is wrong in this code. Its not working. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "users";
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $table_name (name, email,..) VALUES($value1,$value2...)");
```

Comment: Just to point it - make sure you use whatever interfaces (such as `insert()`) that you're given and build your own if needed. Never rely on rewriting the same queries across the app, since you're bound to make a small mistake in one place. In any case, maintenance of these queries becomes difficult over time.